# File Deduplication and Filtering

Tags: windows, file-management, deduplication

I had to run a TestDisk file recovery software on one of my drives. The result was a little over 16,000 files who's names are basically an alpha numeric string. Many of these files contain duplicate or otherwise insignificant content and can be deleted outright.

I can run a batch keyword search within the files using Visual Studio Code, and it works well, but I can't delete/or move the files from the search result without manually locating each file.

How would I, using Windows 10 or another software, filter through the files and batch deleting those with duplicate content, and specific keywords?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @DavidPostill When did I ask for a script or a 'free code service'? This is Super User not Stack Overflow.

My desire was to avoid having to write a fully featured search application as I'd assumed that capability already existed and I just didn't know about it.

As mentioned in my question (Paragraph 2), I used VS Code's keyword search to run locate the files containing the the specified keywords. Additionally I used the integrated windows search, however that wasn't cutting it.

Since then I wrote a threaded PowerShell 7 script to at least start the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Windows Search, looking for text within *non-indexed* files, or a free third-party tool such as [Agent Ransack Lite](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/), which lets you find a file by its contents, and allows you to *delete* any or all matching files? Agent Ransack even shows a preview of the contents, to help make such a decision.

[image: Agent Ransack search]

Comment: Windows built-in search is only searching filenames for me. but I'll take a look at that tool.

Comment: You might view some alternative at https://alternativeto.net/software/agent-ransack/ , too. DocFetcher, for example, is good at indexing many types of files, and FSearch is useful on Linux. grep is exceedingly powerful, but requires knowledge of regular expressions. Note that some proprietary search engines might share file info online!

Comment: Chiming in after a month, Agent Ransack is an amazing tool. Thank you for bringing it to my circle of knowledge, if I could I'd upvote this answer multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use powershell to achieve this. But be careful before deleting. duplicates. Here is an example to list duplicates of **C:\temp** and below:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -File -Recurse | Get-FileHash | Group -Property Hash | WHERE Count -gt 1 | % {
    $firstGroupHashInfo = $_.Group | Select -First 1
    Write-Host "[Hash: $($firstGroupHashInfo.Hash)]"
    Write-Host "  First: $($firstGroupHashInfo.Path)"
    Write-Host "  Duplicates:"
    $_.Group | Select -Skip 1 | % { Write-Host "    $($_.Path)" }
}
```

Comment: I didn't think to try Get-FileHash in powershell. That would automate an otherwise tedious process where I use a shell extension to compare hashes.
--
Somewhat unrelated, I've been experimenting with PowerShell and select-string to do this for files that contain corruption so they at least don't have to be compared. I find however that due to the seemingly random file encoding (UCS-2 Little Endian?!?, ANSI, and UTF) there are many symbols from the extended ascii range that just aren't detected. "Ÿ", "‰", "¢" and "" being the largest PITA to filter out.